# How to pass the access_token as directly to the nuxt/auth package

Tags: javascript, authentication, nuxt.js

How to pass `access_token` to the `user` endpoint in `nuxt/auth` package while you got the access_token as directly without any username and password, I don't want to call `login` before the `user` endpoint because of access_token is already and I just want to call user enpoint, finally how do i pass `access_token` and call the `user` endpoint directly? 
Thanks so much for any help!

```
  // Auth module
   auth: {
    plugins: [
        { src: '~/plugins/auth' }
    ],
    redirect: {
        login: '/login',
        logout: '/',
        home: false
    },
    strategies: {
        local: {
            endpoints: {
                login: { url: 'account/token', propertyName: 'result.access_token' },
                logout: { url: 'account/logout' },
                user: { url: 'account/self', propertyName: 'result' }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set token you could use `this.$auth.setToken(...)`. To call user endpoint you could use `this.$auth.fetchUser()`.

[Docs](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth#fetchuser)